# Looking for a story about a bad queen, living in a ice-castle, opposed by 2 children

Tags: story-identification

I remember an animated cartoon in the 1980's or 1990's about two children, a brother and a sister, who are in a world with a lot of snow, governed by a bad queen who lives in an ice-castle.

In the beginning, the queen is kind, but she want to corrupt the boy (who later became a bad guy with a chivalry-sword).  The queen has injected ice in his heart.

His sister want to save him, with a boring side-kick character ... there was a deer with her, I think.

This was not very well drawn ...
I watched it when I was a child, that's all that I can remember about it.

Comment: Are you sure there weren't four children?

Comment: Sounds a lot like the first half of *The Lion, The Witch, and The Warddrobe*.

Comment: Yes, only 2, a brother and a sister (10 years old I think)

Comment: Haha, yes, a lot of similitudes with Narnia, but that's not Narnia ; there aren't Lion and Warddrobe

Comment: There was a momentum or a deer with the girl while she ... and the queen   has injected ice in his heart

Comment: "a momentum"? Can you provide another word?

Comment: @JackBNimble A cross between that and *Frozen* I think...

Comment: any chance that the queen's name is Elsa ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It could be the 1995 version of [*The Snow Queen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Snow_Queen_%281995_film%29) inspired by Hans Christian Andersen

It has:

- An evil queen who corrupts a boy by sending ice shards into his eyes and heart
- a moose companion
- An ice castle
- from 1995

[image]

A link to the full movie can be found [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGVpocD0-Fo)

Comment: Thank you, but that's not this animated cartoon
The drawings are in a newer style

Comment: There was a momentum or a deer with the girl while she ... and the queen   has injected ice in his heart

Comment: @Mystagogue:
I just realized that we mentioned the same 1995 version. My answer has a YouTube link of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGVpocD0-Fo if you want to grab it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots added.

Comment: YES ! That's it ! Thank you !

Comment: That's some cast. Might watch this later.

Comment: Fun fact: _The Snow Queen_ is actually the story that _Frozen_ was based off of.

Comment: Now, if we can only discover what the OP meant by "momentum"...

Comment: @JohnSensebe I assumed "momentum" was an auto-correction of moose due to its proximity to the word "deer", which is why I mentioned the moose in my answer.

Comment: @Mystagogue, but the word was pasted several times without correction. I believe it to be a translation error rather than auto-correct. Only the OP can say for sure.

Answer (score 8):

Is it possible that it's [the 1957 adaptation of Hans Christian Andersen's *The Snow Queen*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/da/Snejnaya_Koroleva_%28SMF%29.jpg/250px-Snejnaya_Koroleva_%28SMF%29.jpg)?

[image: Screenshot]

It's older animation, and involves an icy land where the boy has been corrupted by the queen. No idea if there's a sword involved. As per the original tale, there are shards of ice in his heart and eyes, which is part of the corruption.

You can find an online copy of [an English dub](https://archive.org/details/the_snow_queen_1959_animation) in the Internet Archive.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it's a 1990's animated cartoon

Comment: There was a momentum or a deer with the girl while she ... and the queen   has injected ice in his heart

Comment: The Queen commands shards of ice to enter the eyes and heart of the boy in this movie.  Perhaps you are looking for a remake of it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very poor drawn version of The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe (1979).

You can see Edmund's interaction with the white Queen and her "kindness" at 17:30.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not this animated cartoon
The drawings are in a newer style

Comment: There was a momentum or a deer with the girl while she ... and the queen   has injected ice in his heart

Comment: @iammg Sounds like when the faun friend of Lucy gets turned to stone by the Queen/Witch, although, that scene doesn't seem to happen in this version.

Answer (score -1):

i believe it was the happily ever after (tv show) episode "ice queen"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If you're going to suggest an alternate answer after one has been marked correct, you need to supply a lot of details showing that this is a better match.

Comment: Or at least enough details to show it's a good match (since answers are also useful if they lead to searchers finding this answer).